# ui-router : How to Make Child State's URL refreshable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show, ng-hide

**TL;DR I have a modal state that I want to have a refreshable link. The modal state is opened with `ng-click` and `ng-show`. How can I make this modal linkable?**

I have a modal window that I've given a custom URL. I have the modal window as a child state (`screenings.images`) in my config, and it shares the same controller as the parent (`screenings`), like so:

```
            .state('screenings', {
                url: '/screenings/',
                templateUrl: 'pages/page.php',
                controller: 'screeningsController'
             })

            .state('screenings.images', {
                url: ":image/",
                controller: 'screeningsController'
            })
```

When an image in the `screenings` view is clicked, the URL navigates to `screenings/red/`, for example.

The modal has an `ng-show` directive attached to it:

```
<div ng-show="show" class="swiper-container">
```

The modal is opened with an `ng-click` on an image container:

```
<div ng-click="swipeShow()" class='img_div'>
```

This function `swipeShow()` and its counterpart `swipeHide()` are in the controller, like this:

```
$scope.swipeShow = function(){
    $scope.show = true;
};

$scope.swipeHide = function(){
    $scope.show = false;
}
```

From here, I'm not sure how to make the modal window URL refreshable.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried giving the child state a completely separate controller:

```
            .state('screenings.images', {
                url: ":image/",
                controller: 'screeningsImagesController'
            })
```

..and then in that new controller, I've tried automatically setting:

```
$scope.show = true;
```

..so that the modal should be set to already displaying. I figured that, if this controller is what is refreshed and loaded in, then it would automatically set `<div ng-show="show=true" class="swiper-container">`, but that's not the case.

Comment: Should I nest views for something like this?

Comment: Add a state parameter with default value true to modal's state: params: { show: true} and then use it in your controller after inserting $stateParams as dependency.